# Catch popup buffers by major-mode with display-buffer-alist?

Tags: major-mode, display-buffer-alist

I would like to catch popup buffers with `display-buffer-alist` by their major-mode instead of matching the buffer name with a regexp.

For example I have dired-mode buffers that popup and I can't come up with proper regexp that would only match dired-mode buffer names.

It would be nice if I could instead do something like this:

```
(setq display-buffer-alist
      '((string= major-mode "dired-mode")
         (display-buffer-same-window)))
```

I understand that their are packages such as [popwin](https://github.com/emacsorphanage/popwin) and [shackle](https://github.com/wasamasa/shackle) that can do this but these packages do not work for my use case.

Comment: I do this by having a catch-all `regexp` and a custom function that handles all incoming buffers that are processed through the `display-buffer-alist` -- if the buffer coming through has a particular major-mode that my custom function looks for, then it is handled according to my pre-programmed method.  I will probably not write up a minimal answer for this particular thread, but if you would like to see a more complex example of how this works, see my previous question/answer on stackoverflow.com:  https://stackoverflow.com/q/18346785/2112489

Comment: FYI:  The most common method for testing the existence of a particular major-mode within a buffer is with the following code snippet:  `(eq major-mode 'dired-mode)`